# difficulties on locating javascript and css codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Hi how can i aces in view model
i saved my css and javascript inside the js folder and css folder inside the application in codeigniter  how can i aces it i'm having difficulties to link them

www
application
         -jsfolder
               -jsfiles
         -cssfolder
                -cssFiles

```
<?php
//birds.php
class Birds extends CI_Controller{

      function index(){
        $this->load->view('birds_view');
      }

      function get_birds(){
        $this->load->model('birds_model');
        if (isset($_GET['term'])){
          $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
          $this->birds_model->get_bird($q);
        }

      }

    }


<?php
//birds_model.php

    class Birds_model extends CI_Model{

      function get_bird($q){
        $this->db->select('bird');
        $this->db->like('bird', $q);
        $query = $this->db->get('birds');
        if($query->num_rows > 0){
          foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['bird'])); //build an array
          }
          echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
        }
      }
    }
    }

bird_view.php


      <style>
        .ui-autocomplete-loading {
          background: #fff url('../link/to/ajax-loading-image') right center no-repeat !important;
        }
        </style>

        <link href="<?php echo base_url().'css/' ?>./css/jquery.ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'js/'?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'js/'?>/js/jquery.ui.js"></script>


        <input type="text" id="birds" />

        <script>
        $(function(){
          $("#birds").autocomplete({
            source: "birds/get_birds" // path to the get_birds method
          });
        });
        </script
```

it only display white screen tnx in advance guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should link your css and js file as:-

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url().'css/jquery.ui.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'js/query.js'; ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'js/jquery.ui.js'; ?>"></script>
```

Comment: note that `base_url()` takes parameters, nicer would be this href `<?=base_url('css/jquery.ui.css')?>`

Answer (score 0):

do your really need that 'dot' after your closing php tag?

`<?php echo base_url(); ?>./`

also remove extra leading slashes:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/jquery.ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.ui.js"></script>
```

p.s make sure that base_url is set properly in your config file: `$config['base_url']='localhost/websitename/'` 
*with a trailing slash*